# Executing a python script in a subprocess - with graphics

Tags: python, wxpython

I've seen a lot of stuff about running code in subprocesses or threads, and using the `multiprocessing` and `threading` modules it's been really easy. However, doing this in a GUI adds an extra layer of complication.

From what I understand, the GUI classes don't like it if you try and manipulate them from multiple threads (or processes). The workaround is to send the data from whatever thread you created it in to the thread responsible for the graphics and then render it there.

Unfortunately, for the scenario I have in mind this is not an option: The gui I've created allows users to write their own plotting code which is then executed. This means I have no control over how they plot exactly, nor do I want to have it. (**Update**: these plots are displayed in separate windows and don't need to be embedded anywhere in the main GUI. What I want is for them to exist separated from the main GUI, without sharing any of the underlying stack of graphics libraries.)

So what I'm wondering now is

*Is there some clean(ish) way of executing a string of python code in a whole new interpreter instance with its own ties to the windowing system?*

---

*In response to the comments:*

The current application is set up as follows: A simple python script loads a wxPython gui (a wx.App). Using this gui users can set up a simulation, part of which involves creating a script in plain python that runs the simulation and post-processes the results (which usually involves making plots and displaying them). At the moment I'm doing this by simply calling exec() on the script code. This works fine, but the gui freezes while the simulation is running. I've experimented with running the embedded script in a subprocess, which also works fine, right up until you try to display the created graphs (usually using matplotlib's show()). At this point some library deep down in the stack of wxPython, wx, gtk etc starts complaining because you cannot manipulate it from multiple threads.
The set-up I would *like* to have is roughly the same, but instead of the embedded script sharing a GUI with the main application, I would like it to show graphics in an environment of its own.

*And just to clarify:*

This is **not** a question about "how do I do multithreading/multiprocessing" or even "how do I do multithreading/multiprocessing within a single wxpython gui". The question is how I can start a script *from* a gui that loads an entirely *new* gui. How do I get the window manager to see this script as an entirely separate application?

The easiest way would be to generate it in a temporary folder somewhere and then make a non-blocking call to the python interpreter, but this makes communication more difficult and it'd be quite hard to know when I could delete the temp files again. I was hoping there was a cleaner, dynamical way of doing this.

Comment: I'm not sure how your app & processes are setup. Could you describe what you have today and how you'd like to have it?

Comment: what (if any) data is shared between your app and the script?

Comment: Almost none. A single object not used by the main GUI is passed to the embedded script. If possible, text output from the script should be captured and passed back to the main GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you simply use [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) to run 'python.exe' and pipe the script in?

Alternatively, the [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing) package should suffice if you want to move some (pickle-able) data over to the new process in which you run the script. Just create a function/callable that runs the script, and create a [Process](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process) object with the callable as target. That way, you should be able to pass some data over, without having GUI issues.

Capturing text with either is easy, subprocess allows that and no more. With multiprocess, you can pass python objects back and forth more easily.

Comment: Passing data is not a problem, plotting from two threads is :)
That's why your first suggestion: running python.exe in a subprocess is probably the best idea :D Hadn't really though of that...

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, you can create window with a parent window from another process, and draw to that.
See the hWndParent argument to [CreateWindowEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632680%28v=vs.85%29.aspxa).

If wxWindows supports getting/setting that explicitly, then you should be good to go.
Depending on your platform, something similar might be possible in any windows system.

So, just giving your users the ability to find the handle of your apps window should give them the option to plot away at views embedded in your app, while running in their own processes.

Comment: Thank you! But I really do need a portable solution, if only because I'm a linux user myself :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't no much about wx, I work with jython(python implemented in java and you can use java) and swing. Swing has its own worker thread, and if you do gui updates you wrap your code into a runnable and invoke it with `swing.invokelater`.

You could see if wx has something like that, if you however are only allowed to manipulate the gui from the thread in which you created it try something similar. create a proxy object for your gui, which forwards all your calls to your thread which forwards them to the gui.

But proxying like this gets messy. how about you let them define classes, with an 'updateGui' function, that they should hand back to you over a queue and that you will execute in your gui thread.

Answer (score 1):

In wxPython land when you use threads, you have to use its thread-safe methods to communicate with the GUI: wx.CallAfter, wx.CallLater or wx.PostEvent. In your case, I would run any long running code in a separate thread/process and when it's done its processing, send the result to the GUI. The GUI can instantiate a new frame and use matplotlib or PyPlot to show the plot, depending on which way you want to go. I've heard you can draw the plot using FloatCanvas too.

Anyway, if you instantiate the new frame correctly, then you can instantiate N frames and show them and be fine. See the wxPython wiki for a few examples of using Threads with wx: http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The problem here is I don't have any control over what plotting methods the user uses (matplotlib, or something completely different) and I don't want to prescribe anything. Piping data back, sharing queueing etc is all stuff I'm familiar with, but in this instance I want to bypass it altogether and run the script as an entirely separate application.

Comment: Well if the plotting can be done any way and you want them to run separately, then you should just use Python's subprocess module. The modules will have to be standalone wxPython scripts, of course. Or they could be PyQT or anything else at that point.

Comment: Thanks! I've already tried it with the multiprocessing module, but that interfered with the running application, will try if it's any different using the subprocess one...

Comment: As I understand it, you have to run the processes in a thread. So you'd spin up a new thread, then use the multiprocessing module. At least, that's what I've read over on the wxPython mailing list.

Comment: The problem is, the way wxpython is tied to Gnome that lets it put little windows on my desktop (can you tell I'm not an expert in this field) doesn't allow changes to the gui from multiple threads or processes. Somehow it recognizes they're all from the same app and you get various crashes, segfaults etc. So what I need is for the window manager system to recognise the script I'm running is an entirely new application. I'll try to make that more clear in the question.

Comment: That's why you have to use wxPython's threadsafe methods to communicate with the main thread from the other threads. Otherwise you get weir behavior.